# PGLS returns an error when referring to variables by their column position in a caper object

Tags: r, phylogeny

I am carrying out `PGLS` between a trait and 21 environmental variables for a clade of plant species. I am using a loop to do this 21 times, once for each of the environmental variables, and extract the p-values and some other values into a results matrix.

When normally carrying each `PGLS` individually I will refer to the variables by their column names, for example:

`pgls(**trait1**~**meanrainfall**, data=caperobject)`

But in order to loop this process for multiple environmental variables, I am referring to the variables by their column position in the data frame (which is in the form of the caper object for PGLS) instead of their column name:

`pgls(**caperobject[,2]**~**caperobject[,5]**, data=caperobject)`

This returns the error:

`Error in model.frame.default(formula, data$data, na.action = na.pass) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'caperobject[, 2]'`

This is not a problem when running a linear regression using the original data frame -- referring to the variables by their column name only produces this error when using the caper object as the data using `PGLS`. Does this way of referring to the column names not work for caper objects? Is there another way I could refer to the column names so I can incorporate them into a `PGLS loop`?

Comment: Please provide some example of what `caperobject` is. It'll be easier to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is to use `caperobject$data[,2] ~ caperobject$data[,5]`, because `comparative.data` class is a list with the trait values located in the list `data`. Here is an example:

```
library(ape)
library(caper)

# generate random data
seed <- 245937
tr <- rtree(10)
dat <- data.frame(taxa = tr$tip.label, 
                  trait1 = rTraitCont(tr, root.value = 3), 
                  meanrainfall = rnorm(10, 50, 10))

# prepare a comparative.data structure 
caperobject <- comparative.data(tr, dat, taxa, vcv = TRUE, vcv.dim = 3)

# run PGLS
pgls(trait1 ~ meanrainfall, data = caperobject)
pgls(caperobject$data[, 1] ~ caperobject$data[, 2], data = caperobject)
```

Both options return identical values for the intercept = 3.13 and slope = -0.003.

A good practice in problems with data format is to check, how the data are stored with `str(caperobject)`.

Comment: Thank you, using caperobject$data[, 2] instead of caperobject[, 2] for example, solved the problem perfectly.